Bash programmable completion (double tab) will not complete in home directory
To be clear, I have tried MANY other answers in this fourm and others and it does NOT work for me. /home/user is also in my PATH variable.
In short, if I have a directory under my $HOME (/home/user1) directory that I put scripts in, named scripts/ .
If I run "vim scr" this completes as I want, showing scripts folder suggested and completing it if I typed out "scri" as it is the only option. However, if I just simply type "scri" it does not show my scripts directory I have to type out the entire name before TAB x2 will simply add "/" to get to that folder. I use this a lot and I can't figure out why it won't complete, this is what I have tried
Note: One oddity that makes me think $PATH isn't working if if I do /home/user/scr this works correctly like vim does above.

Making sure my $HOME directory is in my path through several methods: PATH="~/${PATH:+:${PATH}}"; PATH="$HOME:$PATH"; PATH="/home/user:$PATH"; export PATH="/home/user:$PATH" etc.
Making sure my HOME dir is in my path, it is: echo $PATH |grep /home/user1
~/:/home/user1:./:/home/user1:
Making sure the "bash-completion" package is installed, it is showing bash-completion.noarch                                              1:2.11-5.el9
Removing all previous auto complete entries etc, then doing the above again: complete -r
In case I just totally spaced, I verified I am in the correct dir: pwd
/home/user1

Again if I do /home/user1/scr this works, so why doesn't it understand I am unable to complete without prepending "/home/user1/" can someone give me insight here?

$HOME is a different path as $HOME/scripts. I would just include the latter in the path (not the former, because security). Also note: common is to use $HOME/bin, which your bashrc script may automatically include if it find the directory.

Why you're having trouble
If there is a subdirectory called scripts in the current directory, then when you enter a prefix of scripts and press Tab, bash offers scripts/ as a completion. This is true with an empty bash configuration, after loading bash_completion, and in my personal configuration.
However, there is a limitation (observed on bash 4.3, 5.1 and 5.2, and also on zsh!), which is arguably a bug. When completing command names, if there is no slash, bash first tries to complete command names, and only offers subdirectories of the current directory if no command matches. With a directory called scripts, if you've only typed script or less, then the name of the command /usr/bin/script (and perhaps others, depending on what software is installed on your system) is offered as a completion. Bash will only offer the scripts subdirectory if you type scripts. (Which is completely useless in this particular case, but if, for example, the only command beginning with scr was screen, then bash would start offering scripts as soon as you've typed scri.)
Workarounds
As soon as you include a slash, only directories and executable files are valid completions, so ./s Tab (from your home directory) or ~/s Tab (from anywhere) will offer to complete scripts.
In zsh (with new-style completion), if you enable the autocd option, then subdirectories of the current directory are offered as completions. So scr Tab from your home directory will offer scripts as well as script, screen, etc. For this specific case, though, ./s Tab is likely to require less typing overall. And anyway that bash doesn't do that (which is another bug, I guess).
Why it doesn't matter
PATH lookup is only done when a command name doesn't contain a slash. So putting $HOME in your PATH will not make it possible to run scripts/myscript from anywhere.
Instead, put $HOME/scripts in your PATH and call myscript directly.

This is an awesome explanation!
However after adding "shopt -s autocd" to my bashrc and sourcing, I still cannot autocomplete my directory :(

@ZackFrizzell Oh, indeed, my bad, setting autocd only works with zsh+compinit, it doesn't seem to make a difference in bash (another bug then). I must have gotten confused when testing earlier (perhaps because I did some of my testing in a chroot that doesn't have the same commands in the path...).

I did notice one thing, if I set in .bashrc bind '"\t": complete-filename' this does exactly what I want, showing only folders etc, but it stops the ability for aliases and commands to autocomplete. Why can't they work together???

@ZackFrizzell complete-filename (which is what ESC / does) just completes file names and nothing else: not commands from $PATH and aliases, not variable names after a $, etc. It also completes all file names, not just directories and executable regular files. They don't “work together” because the whole point of TAB is to complete what's generally useful and avoid completing file names where they're meaningless (such as non-executable files in command position).

Going to mark as the answer, I see what you are saying but it seems obvious to me there should be a way to tell bash "If no command matched/entered yet, also show folders/files in current directory, otherwise just do regular completion". Either way your insights were very helpful!!

As one of the alternatives to Tab, the Bash manual offers using Meta-/ to specifically complete filenames.

8.4.6 Letting Readline Type For You
...
complete-filename (M-/)
Attempt filename completion on the text before point.

Meta is usually option on Macs (check if it is enabled in Terminal) or Alt on PCs.

Can you elaborate here? I guess I don't understand if I need to add a command to my .bashrc or if I need to press a key intsead of tabbing or something

@ZackFrizzell After typing scr instead of Tab press Meta + /. It should complete the path scripts/.

apparently in iterm + tmux that is esc + / but that worked!
I still don't like how tab can't do essentially the same but this is reasonable, thanks again!
